# How to start tmux as the default when terminals opened exclude the terminal in Dolphin

Tags: zsh, tmux

I want to set tmux as the default when open terminals (eg. Yakuake, Konsole), but exclude the terminal in the Dolphin file-manager.

I put the following snippet in the `~/.zshrc`

```bash
if [[ -x "$(command -v tmux)" ]] && [[ -n "${DISPLAY}" ]] && [[ -z "${TMUX}" ]]; then
    windowname=$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)
    if [[ ${windowname} =~ ".*Yakuake$" ]] || [[ "${windowname}" =~ ".*Konsole$" ]]; then
        exec tmux
    fi
fi
```

But the command `xdotool getactivewindow` seems always get the wrong active window. So I wrote this snippet in `~/.zshrc` for testing.

```bash
xdotool getactivewindow && xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
sleep 3
xdotool getactivewindow && xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
```

But I get the result as below when Yakuake opened by shortcuts <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd>. It seems that `xdotool` has get the wrong active window name which the last window that activated(in the example is `sublimetext`), and it should be Yakuake.

```bash
94371843
~/.zshrc - Sublime Text
65011722
~ : sleep — Yakuake
```

When Yakuake or Konsole activated by KDE plasma or command line have the same phenomenon.

How can I start tmux as the default when terminals opened exclude the terminal in Dolphin?

---

**Update**: Thanks to [Kamil Maciorowski’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1832883/167207), everything works perfectly after add this snippet in my `~/.zshrc`.

```bash
if [[ -x "$(command -v tmux)" ]] && [[ -n "${DISPLAY}" ]] && [[ -z "${TMUX}" ]]; then
    if [[ ! "$(readlink -f /proc/${PPID}/exe)" =~ "dolphin" ]]; then
        exec tmux
    fi
fi
```

Comment: @Giacomo1968 OKay, keep it in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a shell in a terminal in Dolphin will see `/proc/$PPID/exe` as a symlink to `/usr/bin/dolphin` or so. Instead of `xdotool`, use `realpath /proc/$PPID/exe` and build your logic on the result.

`$PPID` is the process ID of the parent of the shell, set when the shell initializes.